# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms .net core calling framework vb

Tags: c#, vb.net, .net-core

I have the following code working in VB framework 4.7.2

```
Using adapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
    adapter.Fill(ds, TableName)
    Dim rds As ReportDataSource = New ReportDataSource("DataSource1", ds.Tables(TableName))  
    Dim local As LocalReport = New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport()
    local.ReportPath = reportFilename
    ' needed for pics
    local.EnableExternalImages = True
    local.DataSources.Add(rds)
    Dim warnings As Warning() = Nothing
    Dim streamids As String() = Nothing
    Dim mimeType As String = Nothing
    Dim encoding As String = Nothing
    Dim extension As String = Nothing
    Dim bytes As Byte()
    bytes = local.Render(RenderType, Nothing, mimeType, encoding, extension, streamids, warnings)
    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(outputFilename) Then
        My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(outputFilename)
    End If
    File.WriteAllBytes(outputFilename, bytes)
    Return bytes.Length
End Using
```

The project has package references

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Report.Viewer">
      <Version>11.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.VS2010">
      <Version>10.0.40219.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

This works fine in a library called from .net framework 4.7.2
However if I call the library from a .net core 6 library I get the following error.

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms,
> Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
> The system cannot find the file specified

The same relevant files are present, in particular

```
Microsoft.ReportViewer.Winforms.dll
Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll
Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.dll
```

I have asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71073041/how-can-i-tell-if-net-framework-winforms-code-is-callable-from-net-core6) related question.

Comment: .Net Framework and .Net Core / .Net 5+ are not compatible.

Comment: https://github.com/lkosson/reportviewercore

Comment: @Jimi I am searching for where I heard  .net6 was compatible. Certainly I have been able to invoke a 4.7.2 winform at runtime from .net6 ok.

Comment: The source code is *compatible* (it's the same thing, except, possibly, some `using` directives), the assemblies are not.