# How can I tell if .net framework winforms code is callable from .net core6?

Tags: c#, .net-core, vb6-migration

I tried a simple proof of concept creating a solution with one of each project and displaying a Framework 4.7.2 MessageBox.Show("Hello world"). This worked fine, as did displaying a winform.

However I have run into problems referencing dlls.
If I reference a .net framework dll in my .net core6 project I see a small yellow triangle against the package reference and a message

> Package 'MyDLL 2.0.0-CI-20220210-212727' was restored
> using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2,
> .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1,
> .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of
> the project target framework 'net6.0-windows7.0'. This package may not
> be fully compatible with your project.

I guess I could just put my framework winforms code in a .exe and call it via a command line shell.  But I was hoping for a better way, whilst still not doing the full .net core port.

I need the mid step because I have common code that is used by vb6 via com interop.

Is there any better strategy than just try and see?

I have asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71072318/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-reportviewer-winforms-net-core-calli) related question.

Comment: When you're .NET Core you're .NET Core all the way. No, you can't just use a Framework assembly in Core without porting it (except in really trivial cases where the assembly uses, say, nothing more than .NET 2 metadata and no platform-specific code, but that's vanishingly unlikely -- most such code would target some version of .NET Standard). COM interop is a scenario that should actually be possible in .NET 6, although I'm not familiar with the details, but to make that work in one process you'll need to recompile the assembly regardless.

Comment: I guess not seeing the yellow triangle is the answer.

Comment: I asked a related question ~https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71086536/can-i-write-a-winforms-ui-that-is-callable-from-both-net6-and-vb6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hint is the yellow triangle showing in the nuget packages in VS2022.

As Jeroen says, I should not use the framework library without porting it to core.